# LLVM/Clang use opt to show linked ll file

Tags: clang, llvm

I had two c files and want show IR for its linked bit code

link1.c

```
#include "link2.h"
int main() {
  int a;
  int b;
  foo(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

link2.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

link2.c

```
#include "link2.h"
void foo(int a, int b) {
  printf("%d\n", a);
  printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

I did the following command to get bc file.

```
clang -o0 -emit-llvm file1.c -c -o file1.bc
clang -o0 -emit-llvm file2.c -c -o file2.bc
llvm-link -o link.bc link1.bc link2.bc
```

When I tried `lli link.bc` and `llvm-dis link.bc` it run correctly and showed linked ll file, but when I use `opt link.bc -S -o link.ll` to get ll file it just reported segmentation error. Can anyone let me know what to do with `opt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is because version compatible issue of opt. I should use a 3.5 version but turns out I was using 3.4.2.